# Failed authentication using auth code

Tags: community, oauth2, oauth

I am trying to get access_token using authenticate method of `nforce`. I am doing everything right, but it still gives,

```
Error: invalid_grant - authentication failure.
```

Here's my code:

```
var nforce = require('nforce');
var port = 3333;
var org = nforce.createConnection({
  clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  clientSecret: 'xxxxxxxxx',
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3333/getAccessToken'
});


var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/getAccessToken', function(req,res) {
  console.log(req.query.code);
  org.authenticate({ code: req.query.code }, function(err, resp){
    console.log(err, resp);
  });
});

app.listen(port, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    return;
  }
  console.log('Server running on ', port);
});
```

And I've also tried same with the POST call to 
`https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token`, still same error.

I am thinking maybe it's some settings issue in my SF connected app.

Can anyone help me out here? Thanks!

Comment: Where are you posting to. Should end in authorize. Also you seem to be missing the response_type param

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm, in this doc, I have successfully completed 1st 3 steps but stuck at 4th one. And 4th one don't have response_type param

Comment: Then you are missing grant_type. Please update your question to be more clear and specific. It's hard to guess what you are doing and where you are stuck. [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the issue myself.
After changing redirectUrl from 'https://successivesoftware.keka.com/#/me/attendance' to 'localhost', it worked.

Here's some sample code for `nodejs` using `express` and `nforce`.

```
var nforce = require('nforce');
var port = 3333;
var org = nforce.createConnection({
clientId: 'xxxxxxx',
clientSecret: 'xxxxxx',
redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3333/getAccessToken'
});

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/getAccessToken', function(req,res) {
console.log(req.query.code);
org.authenticate({ code: req.query.code }, function(err, resp){
console.log(err, resp);
});
});

app.listen(port, function (err) {
if (err) {
return;
}
console.log('Server running on ', port);
});
```

Hope it helps other like me.